# in button add image to button on click

Tags: swiftui

I have a button with a background Image and Text overlaid, when I click the button I want to remove the text from the button and replace with an image. I'm stuck how to get a reference to the button in the action to add the image.

```
Button(action: {
  print("3 clicked")
  self.background(Image("cross100x100"))
  self.disableButton = true
}) {
  Text("Button text")
}
.disabled(disableButton)
```

The above code doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when I click the button I want to remove the text from the button and
>   replace with an image

I'm not sure why `disableButton` is here, but for above the approach might be as follows

```swift
@State private var clicked = false

...

Button(action: {
  self.clicked = true
}) {
  if self.clicked {
     Image("cross100x100")
  } else {
     Text("Button text")
  }
}
```